# How do I set an environment variable in Makefile for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
PYTHON = python
.DEFAULT_GOAL = help
help:
    @echo ------------------------------Makefile for Flask app------------------------------
    @echo USAGE:
    @echo   make dependencies           Install all project dependencies
    @echo       make docker             Run Docker
    @echo       make env                Set environment variables
    @echo       make run                Run Flask app
    @echo       make test               Run tests for app
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dependencies:
    @pip install -r requirements.txt
    @pip install -r dev-requirements.txt
docker:
    docker compose up

env:
    @set CS_HOST_PORT=5000
    @set CS_HOST_IP=127.0.0.1
    @set DATABASE_URL=postgresql://lv-python-mc:575@127.0.0.1:5482/Realty_DB
    @set REDIS_IP=127.0.0.1
    @set REDIS_PORT=6379
run:
    ${PYTHON} app.py    test:
    @${PYTHON} -m pytest
```

The `set` command doesn't work and the environment variables aren't set, what may be the problem?

Comment: How do you know that the variables aren't set?

Comment: @MadScientist when I try to run `echo %CS_HOST_PORT%` in cmd for example, it doesn't work. Also my project uses this variables from `os.environ` and it returns `KeyError`.

Comment: It's not possible for a makefile to set up your environment.  A makefile runs commands in a separate instance of a shell.  Just like if you have two `cmd.exe` windows open and you set a variable in one of them, it's not set in the other one.  That's the same way make works.

Comment: @MadScientist so there's no way to set environment variables using make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly set environment variables that will be in effect for *programs make will invoke*.  But `make` cannot set environment variables for *shells that invoke make*.  So if your makefile runs a program then you can set an environment variable in your makefile that will be visible in that program.

This has nothing to do with make, by the way.  This is a limitation (or feature, depending on your perspective) of the operating system.  Try this experiment:

- Open a terminal.
- Run `set FOO=bar`
- Run `echo %FOO%`.  See that it prints `bar`.
- From that *same* terminal start a new shell by running `cmd.exe`
- Now here run `set FOO=nobar`
- Run `echo %FOO%`.  See that it prints `nobar`.
- Now exit the new shell by running `exit`
- Now run `echo %FOO%`

You'll see that instead of `nobar`, it still prints `bar`.  That's because the OS does not allow a child program to modify the environment of its parent program.

So, there's nothing make can do about this.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
...
env:
  @echo @echo off > env.bat
  @REM      ===  ^^^ Only SINGLE ONE Sign HERE !!!  ===
  @echo set CS_HOST_PORT=5000 >> env.bat
  @echo set CS_HOST_IP=127.0.0.1 >> env.bat
  @echo set DATABASE_URL=postgresql://lv-python-mc:575@127.0.0.1:5482/Realty_DB >> env.bat
  @echo set REDIS_IP=127.0.0.1 >> env.bat
  @echo set REDIS_PORT=6379 >> env.bat
  @REM  === +5 lines below ===
  @echo ${PYTHON} app.py    test: >> env.bat
  @echo echo %ERRORLEVEL%  >> env.bat
  @echo @${PYTHON} -m pytest >> env.bat
  @echo echo %ERRORLEVEL%  >> env.bat
  @del /Q env.bat

run:
  call env.bat
```

Comment: There exist "SETX" command in Win10+ , ... but you have to open a new cmd.exe to inject these environment..